# Writing a Custom Setter for my Variable - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, swift, setter

I am trying to run a Setter on a property when it changes, that will then also affect the logic in that class:

Here is how it used to look in Objective - C:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

*Set Method for fetchedResultsController:*

```
- (void)setFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchResultsContrller
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *oldfetchResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
    if (newFetchResultsContrller != oldfetchResultsController) {
        _fetchedResultsController = newFetchResultsContrller;
        newFetchResultsContrller.delegate = self;
        if ((!self.title || [self.title isEqualToString:oldfetchResultsController.fetchRequest.entity.name]) && (!self.navigationController || !self.navigationItem.title)) {
            self.title = newFetchResultsContrller.fetchRequest.entity.name;
        }
        if (newFetchResultsContrller) {

            [self performFetch];
        } else {

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt in Swift. However I cannot get the newFetchResultsController, thus cannot complete rest. Is this the right way of setting a property in swift ? How can I do the same principle as above shown in Objective C in Swift?

```
var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController! {
    willSet {
        println("Set fetchedResultsController Called")
        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        performFetch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPD:**
Today with Swift 3.0 your logic can be reimplemented, you may have single plain stored property with only `didSet` value observer specified like this:

```
var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController? {
    didSet(oldfetchResultsController) {
        // If value BEFORE it was set is not identical to value AFTER it was set.
        if oldfetchResultsController !== fetchedResultsController {
            // Let's assume there is such method.
            if fetchedResultsController.isBadAndNotSuitable == false {
                // Do your stuff here.
            } else {
                // If you want to override value that was set
                // without observers being called, you can just set
                // your property inside didSet like:
                fetchedResultsController = nil
                // Or, if you don't want to change value:
                fetchedResultsController = oldFetchedResultsController
                // this won't cause willSet to fire and your property
                // will preserve its value.
                // It's ok to override observers in subclasses, because
                // super's implementation will be called as well before.
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**As it were in 2014:**
You may write it like this:

```
var _fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController? {
    get {
        return _fetchedResultsController
    }
    set (aNewValue) {
        if (_fetchedResultsController != aNewValue)
        {
            _fetchedResultsController = aNewValue
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach you can prevent value to be set. So, for example, if there was a property on `NSFetchedResultsController` called `isBadAndNotSuitable` you could write:

```
set (aNewValue) {
    if (aNewValue.isBadAndNotSuitable)
    {
        NSLog("Don't set, it's bad")
    }
    else
    {
        _fetchedResultsController = aNewValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside `willSet` you have a hidden var called `newValue` that you can use like you are doing in obj-c, like this:

```
willSet {
    if newValue != fetchedResultsController {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This `newValue` variable contains the value you just tried to assign to the property.